Verifying that a iFrame launched popup with a certain title for a Playwright test
I'm new to automation testing and using playwright. I'm trying to just verify that when I click the print button from my dialog popup. The correct report launches. Everything I have tried is giving me a false positive result. Below is my code, the html code, and iframe code. Any help would be appreciated. I have been looking at this for 3 days now.
test('Print FI report within the report', async () => {
        // Create new report
        await homePage.addNewFieldInterviewReport();

        // Enter New Location and Contact Date/Time
        await report.openGeneralSection();
        streetAddress = await generalSection.fillInUniqueOccurredLocation();
        contactDate = await generalSection.pickTodayContactDate();
        contactTime = await generalSection.pickNowContactTime();
        await generalSection.page.waitForTimeout(twoSecTimeout);

        //Click on the print icon within the report
        await report.click(report.CommonSelectors.reportPrint);

        //Select report type and test the modal
        expect(await report.isElementVisible(report.CommonSelectors.printModal.header)).toBe(true);
        await report.click(report.CommonSelectors.printModal.cancelBtn);
        await report.click(report.CommonSelectors.reportPrint);
        expect(await report.isElementVisible(report.CommonSelectors.printModal.header)).toBe(true);
        await report.click(report.CommonSelectors.printModal.reportType);
        await report.click(report.BaseSelectors.dropDown.firstOption);
        await report.click(report.CommonSelectors.printModal.nextBtn);
        //wait for the iframe to load
        await page.waitForTimeout(actionTimeout * 2);
        expect(page.frameLocator('iframe').getByTitle('Field Interview Detail'));
        //Closing the browser page to close the iframe
        await page.close();

From the browser debug tools of the main website:
<iframe src="blob:https://reportwriting-client.dev.publicsafety.tylerapp.com/700437f7-727c-4e7c-bb20-487e7cc80cb6" title="Field Interview Detail" style="display: none;"></iframe>

From inspecting the iframe popup (it is basically like the browser print preview):
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="focus-outline-visible"><head>
  <title>FieldInterviewDetail</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
  <base href="chrome://print">
  <style>
    html {
      background: white;
      /* Remove 300ms delay for 'click' event, when using touch interface. */
      touch-action: manipulation;
    }

    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
      html {
        background: rgb(40, 41, 44);
      }
    }

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .loading body {
    }

    .loading body::before {
      background: rgb(218, 220, 224);  /* --google-grey-300 */
      border-bottom-width: 0;
      border-color: rgb(232, 234, 237);
      border-inline-end-width: 1px;
      border-inline-start-width: 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-top-width: 0;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      width: calc(100% - 385px);  /* --print-preview-sidebar-width */
    }

    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
      .loading body::before {
        background: rgb(95, 99, 104);  /* --google-grey-700 */
        border-color: rgba(40, 41, 44, .9);
      }
    }
  </style>
<cr-iconset name="print-preview" size="24">
  <svg>
    <defs>
      
      <g id="short-edge" viewBox="0 0 26 20" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M2 14v2h2v-2H2zm12 4v2h2v-2h-2zm4 0v2h2v-2h-2zm3.556-18H4.444C3.1 0 2 1.35 2 3v6h2V2h18v7h2V3c0-1.65-1.1-3-2.444-3zM24 18h-2v2c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2zM0 10v2h26v-2H0zm6 8v2h2v-2H6zm16-4v2h2v-2h-2zm-12 4v2h2v-2h-2zm-8 0c0 1.1.9 2 2 2v-2H2z">
        <path d="M29-6v32H-3V-6z">
      </path></path></g>
      <g id="long-edge" viewBox="0 0 23 22" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M17 20h2v-2h-2v2zm4-12h2V6h-2v2zM0 4v14c0 1.1 1.35 2 3 2h6v-2H2V4h7V2H3c-1.65 0-3 .9-3 2zm21-2v2h2c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM10 22h2V0h-2v22zm11-6h2v-2h-2v2zM17 4h2V2h-2v2zm-4 16h2v-2h-2v2zm0-16h2V2h-2v2zm8 8h2v-2h-2v2zm0 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2h-2v2z">
        <path d="M-5-5h32v32H-5z">
      </path></path></g>

    

      
      <g id="business"><path d="M12 7V3H2v18h20V7H12zM6 19H4v-2h2v2zm0-4H4v-2h2v2zm0-4H4V9h2v2zm0-4H4V5h2v2zm4 12H8v-2h2v2zm0-4H8v-2h2v2zm0-4H8V9h2v2zm0-4H8V5h2v2zm10 12h-8v-2h2v-2h-2v-2h2v-2h-2V9h8v10zm-2-8h-2v2h2v-2zm0 4h-2v2h2v-2z"></path></g>
      <g id="print"><path d="M19 8H5c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 3v6h4v4h12v-4h4v-6c0-1.66-1.34-3-3-3zm-3 11H8v-5h8v5zm3-7c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1s.45-1 1-1 1 .45 1 1-.45 1-1 1zm-1-9H6v4h12V3z"></path></g>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</cr-iconset><cr-iconset name="cr20" size="20">
  <svg>
    <defs>
      
      <g id="block">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10 0C4.48 0 0 4.48 0 10C0 15.52 4.48 20 10 20C15.52 20 20 15.52 20 10C20 4.48 15.52 0 10 0ZM2 10C2 5.58 5.58 2 10 2C11.85 2 13.55 2.63 14.9 3.69L3.69 14.9C2.63 13.55 2 11.85 2 10ZM5.1 16.31C6.45 17.37 8.15 18 10 18C14.42 18 18 14.42 18 10C18 8.15 17.37 6.45 16.31 5.1L5.1 16.31Z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="cloud-off">
        <path d="M16 18.125L13.875 16H5C3.88889 16 2.94444 15.6111 2.16667 14.8333C1.38889 14.0556 1 13.1111 1 12C1 10.9444 1.36111 10.0347 2.08333 9.27083C2.80556 8.50694 3.6875 8.09028 4.72917 8.02083C4.77083 7.86805 4.8125 7.72222 4.85417 7.58333C4.90972 7.44444 4.97222 7.30555 5.04167 7.16667L1.875 4L2.9375 2.9375L17.0625 17.0625L16 18.125ZM5 14.5H12.375L6.20833 8.33333C6.15278 8.51389 6.09722 8.70139 6.04167 8.89583C6 9.07639 5.95139 9.25694 5.89583 9.4375L4.83333 9.52083C4.16667 9.57639 3.61111 9.84028 3.16667 10.3125C2.72222 10.7708 2.5 11.3333 2.5 12C2.5 12.6944 2.74306 13.2847 3.22917 13.7708C3.71528 14.2569 4.30556 14.5 5 14.5ZM17.5 15.375L16.3958 14.2917C16.7153 14.125 16.9792 13.8819 17.1875 13.5625C17.3958 13.2431 17.5 12.8889 17.5 12.5C17.5 11.9444 17.3056 11.4722 16.9167 11.0833C16.5278 10.6944 16.0556 10.5 15.5 10.5H14.125L14 9.14583C13.9028 8.11806 13.4722 7.25694 12.7083 6.5625C11.9444 5.85417 11.0417 5.5 10 5.5C9.65278 5.5 9.31944 5.54167 9 5.625C8.69444 5.70833 8.39583 5.82639 8.10417 5.97917L7.02083 4.89583C7.46528 4.61806 7.93056 4.40278 8.41667 4.25C8.91667 4.08333 9.44444 4 10 4C11.4306 4 12.6736 4.48611 13.7292 5.45833C14.7847 6.41667 15.375 7.59722 15.5 9C16.4722 9 17.2986 9.34028 17.9792 10.0208C18.6597 10.7014 19 11.5278 19 12.5C19 13.0972 18.8611 13.6458 18.5833 14.1458C18.3194 14.6458 17.9583 15.0556 17.5 15.375Z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="delete">
        <path d="M 5.832031 17.5 C 5.375 17.5 4.984375 17.335938 4.65625 17.011719 C 4.328125 16.683594 4.167969 16.292969 4.167969 15.832031 L 4.167969 5 L 3.332031 5 L 3.332031 3.332031 L 7.5 3.332031 L 7.5 2.5 L 12.5 2.5 L 12.5 3.332031 L 16.667969 3.332031 L 16.667969 5 L 15.832031 5 L 15.832031 15.832031 C 15.832031 16.292969 15.671875 16.683594 15.34375 17.011719 C 15.015625 17.335938 14.625 17.5 14.167969 17.5 Z M 14.167969 5 L 5.832031 5 L 5.832031 15.832031 L 14.167969 15.832031 Z M 7.5 14.167969 L 9.167969 14.167969 L 9.167969 6.667969 L 7.5 6.667969 Z M 10.832031 14.167969 L 12.5 14.167969 L 12.5 6.667969 L 10.832031 6.667969 Z M 5.832031 5 L 5.832031 15.832031 Z M 5.832031 5 ">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="domain">
        <path d="M2,3 L2,17 L11.8267655,17 L13.7904799,17 L18,17 L18,7 L12,7 L12,3 L2,3 Z M8,13 L10,13 L10,15 L8,15 L8,13 Z M4,13 L6,13 L6,15 L4,15 L4,13 Z M8,9 L10,9 L10,11 L8,11 L8,9 Z M4,9 L6,9 L6,11 L4,11 L4,9 Z M12,9 L16,9 L16,15 L12,15 L12,9 Z M12,11 L14,11 L14,13 L12,13 L12,11 Z M8,5 L10,5 L10,7 L8,7 L8,5 Z M4,5 L6,5 L6,7 L4,7 L4,5 Z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="kite">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4.6327 8.00094L10.3199 2L16 8.00094L10.1848 16.8673C10.0995 16.9873 10.0071 17.1074 9.90047 17.2199C9.42417 17.7225 8.79147 18 8.11611 18C7.44076 18 6.80806 17.7225 6.33175 17.2199C5.85545 16.7173 5.59242 16.0497 5.59242 15.3371C5.59242 14.977 5.46445 14.647 5.22275 14.3919C4.98104 14.1369 4.66825 14.0019 4.32701 14.0019H4V12.6667H4.32701C5.00237 12.6667 5.63507 12.9442 6.11137 13.4468C6.58768 13.9494 6.85071 14.617 6.85071 15.3296C6.85071 15.6896 6.97867 16.0197 7.22038 16.2747C7.46209 16.5298 7.77488 16.6648 8.11611 16.6648C8.45735 16.6648 8.77014 16.5223 9.01185 16.2747C9.02396 16.2601 9.03607 16.246 9.04808 16.2319C9.08541 16.1883 9.12176 16.1458 9.15403 16.0947L9.55213 15.4946L4.6327 8.00094ZM10.3199 13.9371L6.53802 8.17116L10.3199 4.1814L14.0963 8.17103L10.3199 13.9371Z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="menu">
        <path d="M2 4h16v2H2zM2 9h16v2H2zM2 14h16v2H2z"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="password">
        <path d="M5.833 11.667c.458 0 .847-.16 1.167-.479.333-.333.5-.729.5-1.188s-.167-.847-.5-1.167a1.555 1.555 0 0 0-1.167-.5c-.458 0-.854.167-1.188.5A1.588 1.588 0 0 0 4.166 10c0 .458.16.854.479 1.188.333.319.729.479 1.188.479Zm0 3.333c-1.389 0-2.569-.486-3.542-1.458C1.319 12.569.833 11.389.833 10c0-1.389.486-2.569 1.458-3.542C3.264 5.486 4.444 5 5.833 5c.944 0 1.813.243 2.604.729a4.752 4.752 0 0 1 1.833 1.979h7.23c.458 0 .847.167 1.167.5.333.319.5.708.5 1.167v3.958c0 .458-.167.854-.5 1.188A1.588 1.588 0 0 1 17.5 15h-3.75a1.658 1.658 0 0 1-1.188-.479 1.658 1.658 0 0 1-.479-1.188v-1.042H10.27a4.59 4.59 0 0 1-1.813 2A5.1 5.1 0 0 1 5.833 15Zm3.292-4.375h4.625v2.708H15v-1.042a.592.592 0 0 1 .167-.438.623.623 0 0 1 .458-.188c.181 0 .327.063.438.188a.558.558 0 0 1 .188.438v1.042H17.5V9.375H9.125a3.312 3.312 0 0 0-1.167-1.938 3.203 3.203 0 0 0-2.125-.77 3.21 3.21 0 0 0-2.354.979C2.827 8.298 2.5 9.083 2.5 10s.327 1.702.979 2.354a3.21 3.21 0 0 0 2.354.979c.806 0 1.514-.25 2.125-.75.611-.514 1-1.167 1.167-1.958Z"></path>
      </g>
      
  </defs></svg>
</cr-iconset><cr-iconset name="cr" size="24">
  <svg>
    <defs>
      
      <g id="account-child-invert" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <path d="M24 4c3.31 0 6 2.69 6 6s-2.69 6-6 6-6-2.69-6-6 2.69-6 6-6z"></path>
        <path fill="none" d="M0 0h48v48H0V0z"></path>
        <circle fill="none" cx="24" cy="26" r="4"></circle>
        <path d="M24 18c-6.16 0-13 3.12-13 7.23v11.54c0 2.32 2.19 4.33 5.2 5.63 2.32 1 5.12 1.59 7.8 1.59.66 0 1.33-.06 2-.14v-5.2c-.67.08-1.34.14-2 .14-2.63 0-5.39-.57-7.68-1.55.67-2.12 4.34-3.65 7.68-3.65.86 0 1.75.11 2.6.29 2.79.62 5.2 2.15 5.2 4.04v4.47c3.01-1.31 5.2-3.31 5.2-5.63V25.23C37 21.12 30.16 18 24 18zm0 12c-2.21 0-4-1.79-4-4s1.79-4 4-4 4 1.79 4 4-1.79 4-4 4z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="add">
        <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="arrow-back">
        <path d="M20 11H7.83l5.59-5.59L12 4l-8 8 8 8 1.41-1.41L7.83 13H20v-2z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="arrow-drop-up">
        <path d="M7 14l5-5 5 5z"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="arrow-drop-down">
        <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="arrow-forward">
        <path d="M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="arrow-right">
        <path d="M10 7l5 5-5 5z"></path>
      </g>
      
      <g id="cancel">
        <path d="M12 2C6.47 2 2 6.47 2 12s4.47 10 10 10 10-4.47 10-10S17.53 2 12 2zm5 13.59L15.59 17 12 13.41 8.41 17 7 15.59 10.59 12 7 8.41 8.41 7 12 10.59 15.59 7 17 8.41 13.41 12 17 15.59z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="check">
        <path d="M9 16.17L4.83 12l-1.42 1.41L9 19 21 7l-1.41-1.41z"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="check-circle">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm-2 15l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="chevron-left">
        <path d="M15.41 7.41L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L10.83 12z"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="chevron-right">
        <path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="clear">
        <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="chrome-product" viewBox="0 -960 960 960">
        <path d="M336-479q0 60 42 102t102 42q60 0 102-42t42-102q0-60-42-102t-102-42q-60 0-102 42t-42 102Zm144 216q11 0 22.5-.5T525-267L427-99q-144-16-237.5-125T96-479q0-43 9.5-84.5T134-645l160 274q28 51 78 79.5T480-263Zm0-432q-71 0-126.5 42T276-545l-98-170q53-71 132.5-109.5T480-863q95 0 179 45t138 123H480Zm356 72q15 35 21.5 71t6.5 73q0 155-100 260.5T509-96l157-275q14-25 22-52t8-56q0-40-15-77t-41-67h196Z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="close">
        <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="computer">
        <path d="M20 18c1.1 0 1.99-.9 1.99-2L22 6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2H0v2h24v-2h-4zM4 6h16v10H4V6z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="create">
        <path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="delete" viewBox="0 -960 960 960">
        <path d="M309.37-135.87q-34.48 0-58.74-24.26-24.26-24.26-24.26-58.74v-474.5h-53.5v-83H378.5v-53.5h202.52v53.5h206.11v83h-53.5v474.07q0 35.21-24.26 59.32t-58.74 24.11H309.37Zm341.26-557.5H309.37v474.5h341.26v-474.5ZM379.7-288.24h77.5v-336h-77.5v336Zm123.1 0h77.5v-336h-77.5v336ZM309.37-693.37v474.5-474.5Z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="domain">
        <path d="M12 7V3H2v18h20V7H12zM6 19H4v-2h2v2zm0-4H4v-2h2v2zm0-4H4V9h2v2zm0-4H4V5h2v2zm4 12H8v-2h2v2zm0-4H8v-2h2v2zm0-4H8V9h2v2zm0-4H8V5h2v2zm10 12h-8v-2h2v-2h-2v-2h2v-2h-2V9h8v10zm-2-8h-2v2h2v-2zm0 4h-2v2h2v-2z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="error">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-2h2v2zm0-4h-2V7h2v6z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="error-outline">
        <path d="M11 15h2v2h-2zm0-8h2v6h-2zm.99-5C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zM12 20c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="expand-less">
        <path d="M12 8l-6 6 1.41 1.41L12 10.83l4.59 4.58L18 14z"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="expand-more">
        <path d="M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z"></path>
      </g>
      <g id="extension">
        <path d="M20.5 11H19V7c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-4V3.5C13 2.12 11.88 1 10.5 1S8 2.12 8 3.5V5H4c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2v3.8H3.5c1.49 0 2.7 1.21 2.7 2.7s-1.21 2.7-2.7 2.7H2V20c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h3.8v-1.5c0-1.49 1.21-2.7 2.7-2.7 1.49 0 2.7 1.21 2.7 2.7V22H17c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-4h1.5c1.38 0 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5S21.88 11 20.5 11z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="file-download" viewBox="0 -960 960 960">
        <path d="M480-336 288-528l51-51 105 105v-342h72v342l105-105 51 51-192 192ZM263.72-192Q234-192 213-213.15T192-264v-72h72v72h432v-72h72v72q0 29.7-21.16 50.85Q725.68-192 695.96-192H263.72Z"></path>
      </g>
      
      <g id="fullscreen">
        <path d="M7 14H5v5h5v-2H7v-3zm-2-4h2V7h3V5H5v5zm12 7h-3v2h5v-5h-2v3zM14 5v2h3v3h2V5h-5z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="group">
        <path d="M16 11c1.66 0 2.99-1.34 2.99-3S17.66 5 16 5c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 3s1.34 3 3 3zm-8 0c1.66 0 2.99-1.34 2.99-3S9.66 5 8 5C6.34 5 5 6.34 5 8s1.34 3 3 3zm0 2c-2.33 0-7 1.17-7 3.5V19h14v-2.5c0-2.33-4.67-3.5-7-3.5zm8 0c-.29 0-.62.02-.97.05 1.16.84 1.97 1.97 1.97 3.45V19h6v-2.5c0-2.33-4.67-3.5-7-3.5z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="help-outline">
        <path d="M11 18h2v-2h-2v2zm1-16C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8zm0-14c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4h2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2s2 .9 2 2c0 2-3 1.75-3 5h2c0-2.25 3-2.5 3-5 0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="history">
        <path d="M12.945312 22.75 C 10.320312 22.75 8.074219 21.839844 6.207031 20.019531 C 4.335938 18.199219 3.359375 15.972656 3.269531 13.34375 L 5.089844 13.34375 C 5.175781 15.472656 5.972656 17.273438 7.480469 18.742188 C 8.988281 20.210938 10.808594 20.945312 12.945312 20.945312 C 15.179688 20.945312 17.070312 20.164062 18.621094 18.601562 C 20.167969 17.039062 20.945312 15.144531 20.945312 12.910156 C 20.945312 10.714844 20.164062 8.855469 18.601562 7.335938 C 17.039062 5.816406 15.15625 5.054688 12.945312 5.054688 C 11.710938 5.054688 10.554688 5.339844 9.480469 5.902344 C 8.402344 6.46875 7.476562 7.226562 6.699219 8.179688 L 9.585938 8.179688 L 9.585938 9.984375 L 3.648438 9.984375 L 3.648438 4.0625 L 5.453125 4.0625 L 5.453125 6.824219 C 6.386719 5.707031 7.503906 4.828125 8.804688 4.199219 C 10.109375 3.566406 11.488281 3.25 12.945312 3.25 C 14.300781 3.25 15.570312 3.503906 16.761719 4.011719 C 17.949219 4.519531 18.988281 5.214844 19.875 6.089844 C 20.761719 6.964844 21.464844 7.992188 21.976562 9.167969 C 22.492188 10.34375 22.75 11.609375 22.75 12.964844 C 22.75 14.316406 22.492188 15.589844 21.976562 16.777344 C 21.464844 17.964844 20.761719 19.003906 19.875 19.882812 C 18.988281 20.765625 17.949219 21.464844 16.761719 21.976562 C 15.570312 22.492188 14.300781 22.75 12.945312 22.75 Z M 16.269531 17.460938 L 12.117188 13.34375 L 12.117188 7.527344 L 13.921875 7.527344 L 13.921875 12.601562 L 17.550781 16.179688 Z M 16.269531 17.460938">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="info">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 15h-2v-6h2v6zm0-8h-2V7h2v2z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="info-outline">
        <path d="M11 17h2v-6h-2v6zm1-15C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8zM11 9h2V7h-2v2z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="insert-drive-file">
        <path d="M6 2c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L4 20c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2H18c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V8l-6-6H6zm7 7V3.5L18.5 9H13z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="location-on">
        <path d="M12 2C8.13 2 5 5.13 5 9c0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="mic">
        <path d="M12 14c1.66 0 2.99-1.34 2.99-3L15 5c0-1.66-1.34-3-3-3S9 3.34 9 5v6c0 1.66 1.34 3 3 3zm5.3-3c0 3-2.54 5.1-5.3 5.1S6.7 14 6.7 11H5c0 3.41 2.72 6.23 6 6.72V21h2v-3.28c3.28-.48 6-3.3 6-6.72h-1.7z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="more-vert">
        <path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="open-in-new" viewBox="0 -960 960 960">
        <path d="M216-144q-29.7 0-50.85-21.15Q144-186.3 144-216v-528q0-29.7 21.15-50.85Q186.3-816 216-816h264v72H216v528h528v-264h72v264q0 29.7-21.15 50.85Q773.7-144 744-144H216Zm171-192-51-51 357-357H576v-72h240v240h-72v-117L387-336Z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="person">
        <path d="M12 12c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm0 2c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v2h16v-2c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="phonelink">
        <path d="M4 6h18V4H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v11H0v3h14v-3H4V6zm19 2h-6c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v10c0 .55.45 1 1 1h6c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V9c0-.55-.45-1-1-1zm-1 9h-4v-7h4v7z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="print">
        <path d="M19 8H5c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 3v6h4v4h12v-4h4v-6c0-1.66-1.34-3-3-3zm-3 11H8v-5h8v5zm3-7c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1s.45-1 1-1 1 .45 1 1-.45 1-1 1zm-1-9H6v4h12V3z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="schedule">
        <path d="M11.99 2C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zM12 20c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8zm.5-13H11v6l5.25 3.15.75-1.23-4.5-2.67z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="search">
        <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="security">
        <path d="M12 1L3 5v6c0 5.55 3.84 10.74 9 12 5.16-1.26 9-6.45 9-12V5l-9-4zm0 10.99h7c-.53 4.12-3.28 7.79-7 8.94V12H5V6.3l7-3.11v8.8z">
        </path>
      </g>
      
      
      <g id="settings_icon">
        <path d="M19.43 12.98c.04-.32.07-.64.07-.98s-.03-.66-.07-.98l2.11-1.65c.19-.15.24-.42.12-.64l-2-3.46c-.12-.22-.39-.3-.61-.22l-2.49 1c-.52-.4-1.08-.73-1.69-.98l-.38-2.65C14.46 2.18 14.25 2 14 2h-4c-.25 0-.46.18-.49.42l-.38 2.65c-.61.25-1.17.59-1.69.98l-2.49-1c-.23-.09-.49 0-.61.22l-2 3.46c-.13.22-.07.49.12.64l2.11 1.65c-.04.32-.07.65-.07.98s.03.66.07.98l-2.11 1.65c-.19.15-.24.42-.12.64l2 3.46c.12.22.39.3.61.22l2.49-1c.52.4 1.08.73 1.69.98l.38 2.65c.03.24.24.42.49.42h4c.25 0 .46-.18.49-.42l.38-2.65c.61-.25 1.17-.59 1.69-.98l2.49 1c.23.09.49 0 .61-.22l2-3.46c.12-.22.07-.49-.12-.64l-2.11-1.65zM12 15.5c-1.93 0-3.5-1.57-3.5-3.5s1.57-3.5 3.5-3.5 3.5 1.57 3.5 3.5-1.57 3.5-3.5 3.5z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="star">
        <path d="M12 17.27L18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="sync" viewBox="0 -960 960 960">
        <path d="M216-192v-72h74q-45-40-71.5-95.5T192-480q0-101 61-177.5T408-758v75q-63 23-103.5 77.5T264-480q0 48 19.5 89t52.5 70v-63h72v192H216Zm336-10v-75q63-23 103.5-77.5T696-480q0-48-19.5-89T624-639v63h-72v-192h192v72h-74q45 40 71.5 95.5T768-480q0 101-61 177.5T552-202Z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="thumbs-down">
        <path d="M6 3h11v13l-7 7-1.25-1.25a1.454 1.454 0 0 1-.3-.475c-.067-.2-.1-.392-.1-.575v-.35L9.45 16H3c-.533 0-1-.2-1.4-.6-.4-.4-.6-.867-.6-1.4v-2c0-.117.017-.242.05-.375s.067-.258.1-.375l3-7.05c.15-.333.4-.617.75-.85C5.25 3.117 5.617 3 6 3Zm9 2H6l-3 7v2h9l-1.35 5.5L15 15.15V5Zm0 10.15V5v10.15Zm2 .85v-2h3V5h-3V3h5v13h-5Z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="thumbs-down-filled">
        <path d="M6 3h10v13l-7 7-1.25-1.25a1.336 1.336 0 0 1-.29-.477 1.66 1.66 0 0 1-.108-.574v-.347L8.449 16H3c-.535 0-1-.2-1.398-.602C1.199 15 1 14.535 1 14v-2c0-.117.012-.242.04-.375.022-.133.062-.258.108-.375l3-7.05c.153-.333.403-.618.75-.848A1.957 1.957 0 0 1 6 3Zm12 13V3h4v13Zm0 0">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="thumbs-up">
        <path d="M18 21H7V8l7-7 1.25 1.25c.117.117.208.275.275.475.083.2.125.392.125.575v.35L14.55 8H21c.533 0 1 .2 1.4.6.4.4.6.867.6 1.4v2c0 .117-.017.242-.05.375s-.067.258-.1.375l-3 7.05c-.15.333-.4.617-.75.85-.35.233-.717.35-1.1.35Zm-9-2h9l3-7v-2h-9l1.35-5.5L9 8.85V19ZM9 8.85V19 8.85ZM7 8v2H4v9h3v2H2V8h5Z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="thumbs-up-filled">
        <path d="M18 21H8V8l7-7 1.25 1.25c.117.117.21.273.29.477.073.199.108.39.108.574v.347L15.551 8H21c.535 0 1 .2 1.398.602C22.801 9 23 9.465 23 10v2c0 .117-.012.242-.04.375a1.897 1.897 0 0 1-.108.375l-3 7.05a2.037 2.037 0 0 1-.75.848A1.957 1.957 0 0 1 18 21ZM6 8v13H2V8Zm0 0">
      </path></g>
      <g id="videocam" viewBox="0 -960 960 960">
        <path d="M216-192q-29 0-50.5-21.5T144-264v-432q0-29.7 21.5-50.85Q187-768 216-768h432q29.7 0 50.85 21.15Q720-725.7 720-696v168l144-144v384L720-432v168q0 29-21.15 50.5T648-192H216Zm0-72h432v-432H216v432Zm0 0v-432 432Z">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g id="warning">
        <path d="M1 21h22L12 2 1 21zm12-3h-2v-2h2v2zm0-4h-2v-4h2v4z"></path>
      </g>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</cr-iconset></head>
<body>
  <print-preview-app></print-preview-app>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://resources/css/text_defaults_md.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://resources/css/md_colors.css">

  <script type="module" src="print_preview.js"></script>


</body></html>


    expect(page.frameLocator('iframe').getByTitle('Field Interview Detail')); - this line is getting a false positive. If I change out the value in the getByTitle to something I should not expect. It still is passing. That is how I figured out that I'm getting a false positive. 

I have tried replacing the values and other attributes. I even attempted to use the evaluate function in playwright.
I also have been looking at anything on the internet and tutorials. But, I know I'm missing something.

Should that problematic line have an assertion attached? Something like .toBeVisible()?

There are multiple problems here, and we're missing a runnable [mcve] so it's hard to provide a specific solution. Please define all your methods or remove them if they're irrelevant. expect(page.frameLocator('iframe').getByTitle('Field Interview Detail')); must have an await in front of it and an assertion after it, await expect(...).toBeVisible(), so it's a no-op. ESLint should be able to tell you this. Your other assertions are not auto-waiting. I suggest reading about web-first assertions.

Also, please use the ({page}) => fixture rather than managing your own page. No need for page.close() in Playwright tests.

page.frameLocator('iframe').getByTitle('Field Interview Detail')

won't work because you're already in iFrame when page.frameLocator('iframe') and your title is without whitespace.
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="focus-outline-visible"><head>
  <title>FieldInterviewDetail</title>

Also, you expect isn't finished - so it's not clear what you're trying to do.
expect(page.frameLocator('iframe').getByTitle('Field Interview Detail'));

Suggestions list:

Check if you have multiple iframes on the page to be sure you're getting the right one.

await expect(page.locator('iframe')).toHaveCount(1);


Try to find your iframe by title instead

const frame = page.frame("iframe[title='Field Interview Detail']");
await expect(frame.locator("body")).toBeVisible();


Don't use simple assesrts because they do not auto-retry.

expect(await report.isElementVisible(report.CommonSelectors.printModal.header)).toBe(true)

should be
await expect(report.CommonSelectors.printModal.header).toBeVisible();

